# Why is my REST output being trimmed with an ellipses in PowerShell?

Tags: rest, powershell, export-to-csv

I am using `Invoke-RestMethod` to manage a Websense server.  When I use the following `curl` command to list categories from a terminal my results are as expected:

```
curl -k -u <username>:<password> -X GET https://<ipaddress>:<port>/api/web/v1/categories/all
```

The output I receive is:

[image]

I am trying to take this content and save it into a variable so I can output it to a file (preferably a CSV).  When I attempt to run the command as a variable or when I output the content to a text file my response is trimmed for some reason with an ellipses at the end of the text string.  How do I get the content to output to the file the same as it appears on screen?  Using `fl` gives slightly more data and using `ft -auto` has no effect at all.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriListCat -Method Get -Headers $headers |
    Out-File u:\debug.txt
```

```
Categories                                                             
----------                                                                                                                                                                           
{@{Category Description=Sites that provide access to business-oriented web applications and allow storage of sensitive data, excluding those for web collaboration.; Category Hier...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Invoke-RestMethod` returns the result as a PowerShell object data structure. Convert it to JSON before writing it to a file if you want the output in JSON format:

```
Invoke-RestMethod ... |
    ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 |
    Out-File ...
```

If you want the result as a CSV expand the `Categories` property and export the resulting list as a CSV:

```
Invoke-RestMethod ... |
    Select-Object -Expand Categories |
    Export-Csv 'C:\categories.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: This is the answer thank you!  (I have to wait 6 minutes to mark it as the answer)

Comment: For clarity: if `Invoke-RestMethod` can interpret the response as XML/JSON, it will parse it as a `pscustomobject` type, otherwise returning the response content as if you called `(Invoke-WebRequest).Content`.  The reason for OP's response is `$pscustomobject.ToString()` being called.